# Page to select similar products to Batch

Tags: forms, gui-design, web

[image]

I'm looking for a good UI suggestion in creating this page. From the above picture, as you can see there are two rows with same **Model No:**( B2FR150-150CF8Q1 ) others are different. I want to select these two rows and mention this as a **batch** which is an input for the manufacturing team.

I'm new to this StackExchange platform, plz excuse if this is not the standard format to create a question.

Comment: Hi, you are doing fine. It is good practice to include a screenshot in your question, so it is easier to understand. You should also always show your work or what you have tried, so we are not "doing your work for you".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either have checkboxes to mark the rows and a button at the top
[image]

or buttons in the cells that mark all rows with that model no. as batch.
[image: updated ui]